# Grafana dashboard for grafana internal metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, grafana-dashboard

I've found out that grafana exposes metrics in prometheus format by `/metrics` endpoint.

```
# HELP access_evaluation_duration Histogram for the runtime of evaluation function.
# TYPE access_evaluation_duration histogram
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="1e-05"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="4e-05"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.00016"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.00064"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.00256"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.01024"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.04096"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.16384"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="0.65536"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="2.62144"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_bucket{le="+Inf"} 0
access_evaluation_duration_sum 0
access_evaluation_duration_count 0
# HELP access_permissions_duration Histogram for the runtime of permissions check function.
# TYPE access_permissions_duration histogram
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="1e-05"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="4e-05"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.00016"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.00064"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.00256"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.01024"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.04096"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.16384"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="0.65536"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="2.62144"} 0
access_permissions_duration_bucket{le="+Inf"} 0
access_permissions_duration_sum 0
access_permissions_duration_count 0
# HELP cortex_experimental_features_in_use_total The number of experimental features in use.
# TYPE cortex_experimental_features_in_use_total counter
cortex_experimental_features_in_use_total 0
# HELP deprecated_flags_inuse_total The number of deprecated flags currently set.
# TYPE deprecated_flags_inuse_total counter
deprecated_flags_inuse_total 0
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 7.1713e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0.000175439
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.098852809
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.10101742
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.498411257
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 37.966359807
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 468
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 162
...
```

But I can't find any grafana dashboard to show those metrics.

Could you please help me to find ? I am 100% sure that it should be.

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/?search=internal+grafana

Comment: I've seen it but there are only 16 downloads  - it should be more popular

Comment: "But I can't find any" vs "I've seen it".  IDNK

Comment: This dashboard covers only couple of metrics from grafana /metrics endpoint